# Jenkins: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot

Tags: jenkins

I suddenly received the follwing stacktrace in one of my jenkins jobs.
Prior it was working just fine for months.

Deleting the workspace did not fix the problem.

Some git calls are working, but the checkout fails:

```
Checking out Revision d8f1e31d509dd85ac6c1d8f87f7402a032d2bba2 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f d8f1e31d509dd85ac6c1d8f87f7402a032d2bba2 # timeout=10
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to servername
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        [...]
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileSnapshot
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileBasedConfig.<init>(FileBasedConfig.java:88)
    [...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Remote call on servername failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:961)
    [...]
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
```

Comment: restart jenkins service helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disconnected and reconnected the agent in the jenkins settings under `<jenkins.url>/computer/` and it was working again after that.